# What happens when you update an android app?

Tags: android

What happens when a developer updates an app? Does the user that updates the said app download a whole new app or is the app store smart enough to just download the changes?

Comment: Google Play has smart updates which only download the changed parts of the apk.

Comment: Thanks. That's just what I needed to hear. Can't find any reference regarding this though. The android website just mentions versioning your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Play has smart updates](http://www.pcworld.com/article/261004/google_play_smart_updates_save_data_costs_and_time.html) which only download the changed parts of the apk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google play is smart enough to update just changes called delta update.look at the example video and docs over [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/16/google-flips-the-switch-on-smart-app-updates-in-the-play-store-video/) which updates patch file instead of whole application.