# What happens on an android device when the app updates?

Tags: android

**What is the workflow on devices when the Play Store updates an app? What happens if the user is using the app at the same time?**

I ask because we have some crashes where a String ID cannot be found, and when we looked at the APKs the String resource is available in both versions - but the hex ID reported in the crashes is found in the OLD apk and not in the NEW one. This is strange.

This leads us to think that the Play Store may have updated the app's files and resources while the app was running, and then when it looked up the string resource to load something it used the old ID from memory and of course didn't find it in the newly updated files.. leading to the ResourceNotFound exception.

*How is that possible? Is it even possible?* I'd think not, except we looked in the APKs and the ID that was in the crash matched the old resource id and not the new one that we just pushed.

Comment: As far as I know, the app process must be stopped before the app can be updated. @ShobhitPuri - instant publishing and updating doesn't really address what the Google Play client does with a running app on the device.

Comment: @TedHopp Confirming this. I've been using apps while they update and they always close themselves.

Comment: I just had a similar issue. Although the app is going through onDestroy/onCreate/onResume when updated it didn't reload global static variables. So if you declared a global static variable like static int resId = R.id.something; just put it in onCreate again (resId=R.id.something;).

Comment: @stefple - that sounds like my behavior exactly, only we're getting the crash from a missing String Resource because it's looking for the old one. Surely we shouldn't have to force Android to reload our res/* stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could find in researching this, it seems as though the App *needs* to be closed in order for the files to be reachable for update. Once closed, Google Play updates only the changed pieces of the apk to save time and cost.

There are several forum posts I have found that teach you how to rollback app options from flashed ROM (which happens all the time with rooted devices). Perhaps the user attempted to rollback after receiving the update. Either that, or the ID that was in the crash is referenced in part of your apk that was not updated.

Sources:
[Notification of Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849889/how-to-notifiy-users-about-an-android-app-update)

[What Happens When You Update an App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087714/what-happens-when-you-update-an-android-app)

[Google Play Saves Cost & Time](http://www.techhive.com/article/261004/google_play_smart_updates_save_data_costs_and_time.html)

Comment: I would agree that the app should close in order to do the update, but then how would I be getting String IDs that are only in the old R.java in crash logs from the new app version?

Comment: That's the question, I suppose. It must have something to do with the way R.java stores IDs, or maybe a file that *wasn't* updated referenced that String ID and it was no longer contained in the new R.java, hence the error. Is this something you were able to reproduce, or that happened on a large scale within your user set? Or was this a one-time crash, for one user?

Comment: It happened at the hundreds-of-crashes scale over about 300,000 app upgrades, so not just a one time thing. It is reported in 2.3.x android versions, as well as 4.1.x versions on both tablets and phones.

Comment: In that case I would imagine, based on the 'Smart Update' scenario, that your apk contained a file that referenced the old R.java ID, and was not updated with the rest of the files as it had not been modified. Considering the scope of the affected users, that would be my best guess. Of course, that is just based off my working knowledge of the update process via Google Play, as well as my extremely limited knowledge of your app.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using the app at the same time it's updating the app the linux filesystem allows for the behavior described above.  A process holding a file open (think the app executable while the app is running) will keep the executable image in memory even if the executable on disk has been updated.  What this allows is the new apk to be put in place and unpacked with the old exe image still in memory.

Resource files tend to be lazily loaded, so navigating the old image in memory will look for resources and potentially load a resource from the newly unpacked app.  The resource may not be compatible with the old app and cause a crash.

Comment: Except that Android closes the app if it's running and an update has to be installed for it.

Comment: The big "smoking gun" here seems to be the crash reports from our new app version that contain String IDs only present in the old version's R.java =\

Answer (score 1):

I remember encountering an issue like this one - the issue in my situation was that we were storing resource ids (and even serialized enumerated values) via user preferences. Once our app was updated (new enumerated values, new resources), old values were loaded from user preferences and passed into code, resulting in crashes.

Perhaps this is not your issue, but its worth checking to see that you aren't storing / loading IDs for resources which no longer exist.